# Error while removing item from collection

Tags: c#, linq, collections

Getting error *Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.*

```
var toUpdateItm = MC_CRM_T001A.ItemDetails
    .Where(X => X.CatNo == SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo);
foreach (var itm in toUpdateItm)
{                       
    int x = MC_CRM_T001A.PartDetails.IndexOf(MC_CRM_T001A.PartDetails
        .Where(X => X.cat_item_id == itm.id)
        .FirstOrDefault()
    );
    if (x >= 0 && x!=null)
    {
        MC_CRM_T001A.PartDetails.RemoveAt(x);                    
    }             
}

foreach (var itm in toUpdateItm)
{
    if (itm.CatNo == SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo)
    {
        MC_CRM_T001A.ItemDetails.Remove(itm);
    }          
}
```

Comment: You cannot modify the collection while iterating over it! Do like var toUpdateItm = MC_CRM_T001A.ItemDetails.Where(X => X.CatNo == SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo).ToList();

Comment: Does the code have to modify the existing collection? You can very easily make a new collection with only the items you want, then replace the original collection with the new collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't modify the list you're looping over.  Change for foreach calls to `foreach (var itm in toUpdateItem.ToList())`, which will create a copy of the list, instead.

Also, you can express this code more cleanly without all the IndexOf stuff:

```
 var toUpdateItm = MC_CRM_T001A.ItemDetails.Where(X => X.CatNo == SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo).ToList();
foreach (var itm in toUpdateItm.ToList())
  {
    var item = MC_CRM_T001A.PartDetails.FirstOrDefault(X => X.cat_item_id == itm.id);
    if (item != null) { MC_CRM_T001A.PartDetails.Remove(item); }
    if (itm.CatNo == SelectedCRM_T001A.CatNo) { MC_CRM_T001A.ItemDetails.Remove(itm);
  }
```

You don't need two loops either.